# What days contain in this week

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Start and End Days for a Given Week in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923925/get-start-and-end-days-for-a-given-week-in-php)

Example i use function date('W') will get week of the year.
Suppose get week number 37. Can I get what days in this week Example 2011-09-12 to 2011-09-18

Thank you

Comment: _"How many days contain in this week"_, the answer is always: 7

Comment: Before asking a question, check for similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186431/calculating-days-of-week-given-a-week-number

Comment: Why not produce some code - and if it does not work post it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateTime` and `DatePeriod` classes to work with dates and periods of time.

```
// ISO week to get the days of
$week = '2011W37';

// Date period for the days in the above week
$period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime($week), new DateInterval('P1D'), 6);

foreach ($period as $day) {
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
}
```