# Get first day of week in "Y-m-d" of given week number in the year

Tags: php, date, datetime, format

im trying to get the first day of a given week based on inputting a week number and year. im currently using this for the current week and year and works like a charm.

```
$week = date('W');
$year = date('Y');
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."W".$week.'1'));
```

however when i try to input my own week and year it doesn't work

```
$week = 7;
$year = 2013;
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($year."W".$week.'1'));
```

what type if string should i be using for strtotime? how come providing my own date doesn't work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722585/php-get-first-day-of-week-of-given-week-and-year#autocomment20596575


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923925/get-start-and-end-days-for-a-given-week-in-php

Comment: here is my code for first and last days of given week `$string = $year.'W'.str_pad($week, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
 $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($string.'1'));
 $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($string.'7'));`

Comment: I don't hing this is a duplicate. The linked question wants a week nr from a specific date, this one is the opposite.

Comment: Please nose that "week number" is different across locales: http://www.pjh2.de/datetime/weeknumber/wnd.php?l=en#Legend

Comment: This question is not really a duplicate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php does not contain an answer how to get the first date of the week from a week number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the week numbers are supposed to be padded (and the extra `1` at the end doesn't really do anything):

```
$date1 = date(
    'Y-m-d', 
    strtotime($year . 'W' . str_pad($week, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT))
);
```

Comment: perfect, thought it was something to do with that, thanks!